# Are web servers that support HTTP any more vulnerable to client-run exploits than those that use HTTPS?

Tags: tls, http, exploit

Does HTTPS have any unique mechanisms that protect web servers from exploits run by a malicious client (eg. SQL injection, specific browser exploits etc.)?

My current understanding is that HTTPS is simply a HTTP session run over a TLS 1.2/1.3 tunnel (ideally), and wouldn't protect against any vulnerabilities of the client/server applications running on either end.

Is it correct that TLS only protects against MiTM and that browsers/web servers must be regularly patched to protect against all other exploits?

Comment: HTTP/HTTPS are at the wrong layer - they're below the application layer, and generally most modern web application frameworks don't directly expose it to user code anyways.  If your client is actively malicious, though, **nothing** you do can (completely) protect the client side of the application.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank you for your answer.
"Generally most modern web application frameworks don't directly expose it to user code anyways" so, as you clarified, because HTTP/HTTPS is just the session.. whether the session is encapsulated by TLS will not have any baring on the application-layer exploits a client can run, is that correct?

Comment: While HTTPS can't protect the system (and users) from malicious code operating on the client, it does partly protect the client from being compromised in the first place. If the site uses any third-party scripts (e.g. a library from a CDN), HTTPS ensures that these scripts are fetched only from verified servers. This is really just another protection against MiTM really, but on another connection (one you have no control over whatsoever), so I think it is worth pointing out as a benefit.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are correct; TLS provides no protection at all against malicious clients. You can think of TLS as providing a tunnel between the client and server. What's going through the tunnel is protected against attack *from outside the tunnel*, but it doesn't control what goes through the tunnel at all. Therefore, it doesn't protect against attacks launched *through* the tunnel (in either direction).

Comment: While this is technically correct, modern browsers offer several client security options, which are only available on pages served via https. So if your user is using a modern browser you will get added security benefits of using https!

Comment: @Falco but also only against attackers against the browser. Those also do nothing if the client is intentionally malicious

Comment: @Hobbamok Of course, a malicious client does not need to use a secure browser. But several attacks (like XSS) target friendly users with valid credentials, and if they use a browser, https can protect them.

Comment: @Falco my bad I had misremembered the question, instead of "client-run exploits"  I was thinking about malicious clients, which is why I dismissed your comment. You are absolutely right though

Comment: mTLS my be an exception. It prevents untrusted clients from connecting to your server in the first place, regardless of how buggy your webapp may be.

Comment: @ArcticKona mTLS only protects the server to the extent that you can control and/or trust whatever and whoever has access to the client secret key(s). Generally, this means you not only need to trust the client software to not only not be malicious itself, but also trust that the keys cannot leak. This means that you need to trust anyone who has access to the computer the client software is on, maybe their backups, etc. I can't imagine many situations where this would be practical (and you certainly can't just embed keys in a downloadable app).

Answer (score 10):

In the HTTPS extension, the communication protocol is encrypted using *Transport Layer Security* (TLS) that provides security for the *transport layer*. The web server, web application and web browser vulnerabilities are all *application layer* problems. Therefore, web browsers, web servers and web application all require regular security updates despite the utilization of HTTPS.

A *web application firewall* (WAF) on the server may help filtering malicious content transmitted over HTTPS. That might help protecting your web application from attacks against 0-day vulnerabilities. However, the request must look malicious in general (particularly most SQL injections and XSS vulnerabilities are easy to detect).

Additionally, TLS and its predecessor *Secure Sockets Layer* (SSL) have had vulnerabilities, too. Some have been weaknesses in the protocol itself (weak cipher suites, POODLE, BEAST, CRIME & BREACH) and some on the implementation (e.g. Heartbleed [CVE-2014-0160](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2014-0160)). For this reason, you have to keep your TLS implementation up-to-date, too, and disable [outdated versions of the protocol](https://endoflife.software/protocols/encryption/tls).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide more information/context with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct that TLS only protects against MiTM ... ?

No, that is not correct. Here are also some other aspects:

- TLS provides confidentiality
- TLS provides integrity
- TLS provides protection against replay attacks
- TLS provides forward secrecy

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Three of those I knew already, except:
"TLS provides protection against replay attacks"
So this feature is provided by the MAC. Is there no feature inherent in HTTP that protects against replay attacks?

Comment: You are right that the *goal* of TLS is to protect against all of those attacks. But unless I am badly mistaken, all of them do rely on traffic interception so on something that is related to MiTM.

Comment: @Inquisitive: *"So this feature is provided by the MAC"* - No. MAC provides integrity. Protection against replay attacks is based on nonce.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: No. MiTM has to do with authentication, when you cannot authenticate the other side. In case of replay attack the receiver obtains valid messages from the sender. Protection against MiTM hast nothing to do with protection against replay. Also if you would not use encryption and just sign messages, the traffic would be readable for everyone, but still it would be impossible to modify it. Thus, protection against MiTM hast nothing to do with confidentiality.

Comment: @A.Hersean: We speak about MITM only if there is *relay*. Where as for replay attack there don't have to be any relay. If messages can be recorded and replayed at some other time, *this* is replay. At this time there can be no communication between 2 parties, so there is no relay. Thus the replaying attacker is not in the middle. Thus, protection from MITM does not mean protection from replaying.

Comment: If one has a means of ensuring integrity, JS code running on the client can take care of the rest, sometimes more effectively than https alone.  If there were a variation of http:// that would include a SHA256 hash within the URL, and which would instruct clients to load an entire page and validate the hash before attempting to do anything else with it, then a page with such an address would be fully cacheable by any intermediate waypoints, but JS code on such a page could provide whatever balance of security and caching would best fit application needs.

Answer (score -2):

Using HTTPS, the server is usually MORE vulnerable.

You still have the whole HTTP stack with its potential vulnerabilities exposed AND you now have all the TLS stack vulnerabilities for the attacker to pick from.

TLS vulnerabilities can be impressively bad - see e.g. the OpenSSL Hearthbleed.

---

On the other hand, HTTPS in some sense reduces the probability of the attack success by making it harder to obtain valid user credentials and/or to inject malicious code into the HTTP interaction.

(A lot of attacks are of "privilege escalation" type and require authentication, even if the authenticated user nominally has low privileges in the system.)

This is especially effective if the HTTPS server uses TLS authentication with client certificates. In this case, an attacker without a valid client certificate can only poke the TLS frontend. They will have to break the TLS code or obtain a valid cert + its private key by other means in order to get to the HTTP stack in the first place.

A well-maintained policy of issuing client certs only on hardware tokens may force the potential attacker well into the social engineering domain even if the system has gross HTTP or higher level vulnerabilities.

Comment: The first part of your answer is misleading. While TLS implementation can introduce some bugs and vulnerabilities, it prevents a whole *range* of attacks by providing an authentication of the communication channel, confidentiality of its content, and better reliability (detection of errors) than the poor checksums of HTTP over TCP. Overall, despite a few vulnerability, HTTPS offer better security than HTTP.

Comment: The first part of the answer is in the same answer with the second part.

Comment: @A.Hersean They offer *different kinds* of security. SSL provides security and privacy/confidentiality to connections between clients and servers, but has a risk of worsening the security and privacy of the server. I suppose the rarely-used client authentication could be used to prevent illegitimate clients from interacting with the backend running on the webserver.

Comment: That's awfully false, for instance it is far easier to exploit a non encrypted HTTP connection by intercepting any cookie involving classic ID Session system than finding a new HeartBleed in TLS and be able to succesffuly exploit it. The cause for that is not only the HTTP protocol but also the average competence/budget of developing web site. Also lot of stuff just now assume you will use HTTPS by default (SESSIONID Cookie over https is fine enough, over HTTP you're more in trouble).

Comment: You mean ‘usually has a larger attack surface’, not ’is usually more vulnerable’. There is a big difference there, and it actually _does_ matter in this case.

Comment: The Q specifically asks about "client-run exploits". In this regard, the increased attack surface directly translates into "more vulnerable". There was quite a period in recent years when OpenSSL actually decreased the security. Of course, there are better crypto libs out there, including some of the OpenSSL forks.